# How to make mass correction and conversion characters of vector to the numeric

Tags: r, character, apply

I have a big vector of characters, containing the numbers which I need to correct, and then convert to numeric vector,  for example:

`data.f <- c('11.23', '34,32 + 12,17', '21.1')`

I need to get in result like this:

`num 11.23 34.32 21.1`

I tried to use apply function family to solve this problem

`num <- sapply(data.f, function(x) ifelse(nchar(data.f[x])<6, data.f[x] <- as.numeric(data.f[x]), data.f[x] <- as.numeric(substring(gsub("[,]", ".", data.f[x]), 1,5))))`

I have tried experiment with different options

`num <- sapply(data.f, function(x) ifelse(nchar(data.f[x])<6, as.numeric(data.f[x]), as.numeric(substring(gsub("[,]", ".", data.f[x]), 1,5))))`

***gsub*** - to change come to dot

***substring*** - to cut extra symbols (it would be better to find average)

***as.numeric*** - to convert character to numeric

But at result I get the same as I had:

```
str(num)
- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "11.23" "34,32 + 12,17" "21.1"
```

```
attributes(num) 
$names
[1] "11.23"         "34,32 + 12,17" "21.1"
```

I need help to fide solution, maybe some good human will see what I messed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace the `,` with `.` and use `parse_number` to extract the number

```
readr::parse_number(gsub(",", ".", data.f))
#[1] 11.23 34.32 21.10
```

---

The `ifelse` is vectorized unlike `if/else` (which take one element at a time).  So, we don't really need a loop function (`sapply` is looping each element of the `vector` - for a vector, the unit is single element)

```
ifelse(nchar(data.f) < 6, as.numeric(data.f), 
       as.numeric(substr(gsub(',', '.', data.f), 1, 5)))
#[1] 11.23 34.32 21.10
```

NOTE: `nchar`, `substr`, `ifelse`, `as.numeric` and `gsub` can all take a `vector` with length > 1.

Comment: looks and work nice. thx! But can you show, please, the example of applying a function to each value in variable, by using an apply family? What is the problem with my code?

Comment: @NikitaSnegirev  `ifelse` is vectorized.  So you don't need a loop here.  `sapply` loops through each element  (here the unit is a single element for vector) and then apply the `ifelse`.  instead, the `ifelse` can be directly applied on the whole dataset unlike `if/else`

Comment: @NikitaSnegirev You can do `ifelse(nchar(data.f) < 6, as.numeric(data.f), as.numeric(substr(gsub(',', '.', data.f), 1, 5)))` there would be friendly warning when you convert the character to `numeric` as it would do the conveersion for the full data